# TypeScript "tsd install jquery" - cannot find name "document"

Tags: jquery, typescript, tsd, typescript-typings

I'm trying to import jquery into my TypeScript project.

To do this I ran `tsd install jquery --save` which created me a jquery.d.ts file, and which added `/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />` to my tsd.d.ts file.

When adding `import * as $ from 'jquery';` to the top of the file I'm working on, I then get 77 compile errors from jquery.d.ts.  All are in the form: **cannot find name "document"**.  As well as Document, it can't find: Element, Event, Node, HtmlElement, XmlDocument, Text and XMLHttpRequest

See screenshot below for a few examples:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I need to do?

Comment: as long as jquery.d.ts is not compiled it doesn't matter. It can file on your IDE but in the end it will compile and works

Comment: @iberbeu - when compiling with this file in my VS Code IDE, I get: "Build errors have been detected during preLaunchTask 'npm'." and a list of the 77 errors (which are also underlined in my IDE).

Comment: but jquery.d.ts shouldn't be compiled because your application doesn't need it to run. Try to set it up not to compile jquery.d.ts and then run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting Visual Studio Code (or `Reload Window`)? I do find that it gets confused quite often when declarations get installed or changed.

The types are defined and come as part of Visual Studio Code and are automatically available within VSCode (you should not have to manually reference them):

[image]

Also:

1. Consider using [`typings`](https://github.com/typings/typings), which is the successor to `tsd` (you can still consume type declarations from the tsd library - e.g.: `typings search jquery` and `typings install --save --global dt~jquery` where `dt~` means install from DefinitelyTyped repository)
2. Consider using a `tsconfig.json` file to specify the workspace area for TypeScript and `exclude` the `node_modules` and the `typings`/tsd folders

Comment: +1 for recommending typings over tsd.  Do you have any idea why VS Code wouldn't be able to find those types (I've checked I have the file in the location in your image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\typescript\server\typescript\lib\lib.d.ts)

Comment: @Andy No idea - sorry. Make sure the file type comes up as "TypeScript" in the status bar

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer was enough to tell me that something was wrong with my local install.  I reinstalled a few things and it's all working now as your answer suggested it should.